# Is this infinite sum of matrices convergent?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, functional-analysis, limits

For a matrix $A$, by $||A||$, I mean the matrix-norm induced by the $\ell^2$-norm. Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times p}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ with $||A|| < 1$. Define,
$$
N_k :=
\begin{cases}
CA^{k - 1}B, &\text{if }k \geq 1\\\\
0, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Define, $Q_{ij} := \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{N_k^{\sf{T}} N_{k + i - j}}$.

**Questions:**

1. It seems clear by the submultiplicativity property that $||N_k^{\sf{T}} N_{k + i - j}||\to 0$ as $k\to\infty$ since $||A||^k\to 0$. Is this reasoning valid?
2. Using the same reasoning I believe it is possible to prove that the series of $Q_{ij}$ converges by proving that the partial sums form a Cauchy sequence. Is this reasoning valid?

Comment: Yes and yes. By submultiplicativity, $\|N_k^\mathrm{T} N_{k+i-j}\| \leq \|B\|^2\|C\|^2\|A\|^{2k+i-j-2}$.

Comment: @DavidGao, thanks. That confirms my reasoning.